# I would like remove only spaces and ignore tabs in a string

Tags: regex, perl

String has both spaces and tabs. I would like to remove all the occurrences of spaces in the string but keep the tab spaces as is. 
Would like to preserve the tabs so that I can use tab-delimiter option in excel when I import the text file
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Tabs are ascii character 0x09; spaces are 0x20. Replacing spaces will not affect tabs...

```
$str = "1 2 3\t4 5 6\t7 8 9\n";
$str =~ s/ //g;
# $str is now "123\t456\t789\n"
```

Take a look at [perlrequick](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#Search-and-replace) for an introduction to regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

[I wouldn't usually answer a "write my code for me" question like this, but I thought it was important to have an answer giving an alternative to the existing regex-based answer.]

Whilst you can use `s/.../.../` to remove characters from a string, it's probably overkill to invoke all of the power of Perl's regex engine to do something as simple as that. The transliteration operator (`tr/.../.../`) has a `/d` option that deletes specific characters from its target string.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = "1 2 3\t4 5 6\t7 8 9\n";

print $str;

$str =~ tr/ //d;

print $str;
```

Comment: Great comment, I used this a long time ago and actually forgot about it :)